# const char* to const char**

Tags: c++, pointers, char, type-conversion

Is there a easy way to convert a `const char*` to a `const char**` in C++ (without the use of Boost)? I've tried to use `&myConstCharP` but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're using it for?

Comment: Ya dawg, I heard you liked `char *`, so I put a `char **` into your `const char *` so you can typecast them while typecasting them.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting"?  Do you want a (bit-preseriving) coercion or what?  Or something like taking an object of the first type and then sticking an `&` in front of it?

Comment: This is a prime-example of [the X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you tell us the solution you want, but not the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Can you convert an address of a person (like "Main street 1234") to an address of an address of a person ("page 1234 column 2 line 42 of the phone directory")?

Answer (score 5):

I can't see a problem here. The following code works fine for me:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char c = 'a';
    const char *myConstCharP = &c;
    const char **p = &myConstCharP;

    printf("Your original char is: %c",**p);
}
```

Comment: `const char ***ptr_p = &p;`

`const char ****ptr_ptr_p = &ptr_p;`

and even more!